# SQL Cast/Convert Issue

Tags: sql, sql-server, casting

This is more like a help from experts than a question. I need to declare a variable called BillingYear which I can assign it to a year. The problem is:

I do not know which data type it should be! I know this is so simple but... the problem is, in our database we do not have a year column. we have something called fiscal year which starts from 07/01/any year - and end 06/30/nextyear

I want to find a way that I enter a year, the year will be added to the fiscalstart, fiscalend variables which they are datetime variables. I tried this but it is not working!

```
DECLARE
@Year int, --Here I thought I can assign year to any year then do the following:

DECLARE
@fiscalstart datetime = '07/01/' + @Year,
@fiscalend datetime = '06/30/' + @Year+1
```

Then I can use that to calculate the billingMonth by billingMonth  = fn_Fiscal(@fiscalstart, @fiscalend )// you really do not need to know this part but I just wanted to show you why I need to do all this complicated steps.
What is the best way to approach this problem?

Comment: For starters, you don't need `@fiscalend`. Your query should be `>= @fiscalstart AND < DATEADD(YEAR, 1, @fiscalend)`. This way you don't have to do any messy `BETWEEN` logic [that may ignore data on the last day or round in unexpected ways due to the underlying data type](https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common.aspx).

Comment: To determine `@fiscalstart`, don't try to add integers to poorly formatted regional date strings. Use date math. `SET @fiscalstart = DATEADD(MONTH, 6, DATEADD(YEAR, @Year-2000, '20000101'));`

Comment: You probably have a table called FiscalYear or Period or something like that. Select (at)fiscalstart and (at)fiscalend from that table, using whatever is the primary key, e.g WHERE FiscalYear.ID = '2013' or maybe WHERE Period.FY = 2013. The (at)fiscalstart variables should be the right datatype for use with the corresponding functions like fn_Fiscal(). Saves converting integers into strings into datetimes. Just use what is already there, what people have already built.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't add an int to a string and better to use a DMY order agnostic format such as `yyyymmdd`;

```
DECLARE @Year int = 2013
DECLARE @fiscalstart datetime = cast(@Year as varchar(4)) + '0701'
```

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of issues here first you need to make sure the string you are trying to cast into a date time is in the right [format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186724.aspx). Then you need to cast you year var to a string or you will get a type mismatch. Here are some examples.

```
DECLARE @year INT
SET @year = 2012

DECLARE @debugDate1 DATETIME
SET @debugDate1 = '07/01/' + CAST(@year AS VARCHAR(MAX)) + ' 00:00:00'
SELECT @debugDate1

DECLARE @debugDate2 DATE
SET @debugDate2 = '07/01/' + CAST(@year AS VARCHAR(MAX))
SELECT @debugDate2
```

Answer (score 1):

@fiscalstart and @fiscalend are defined as datetimes, so the object you set them to has to be a datetime.

you are taking a string '07/01/' and trying to add an integer to it.  this won't work.

you need to do something like:

```
SET @fiscalstart = '07/01/' + CAST(@Year as VARCHAR)
```

Comment: This works but now, I need to cast the new fiscalstart to datetime!

Comment: `DECLARE @year int
SET @year = 2013

DECLARE @x as datetime

SET @x = '07/01/' + CAST(@year as varchar)

PRINT @x`

This script works, but you could always wrap the string addition expression in a cast if it's causing you problems.

`CAST('07/01/' + CAST(@year as varchar) AS DATETIME)`

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Sql Server 2012, you can use this (test **[here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/5486)**):

```
SELECT DATEFROMPARTS (2010, '07', '01' ) AS Result;
```

For more information please see this **[link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213228.aspx)**.

**DATEFROMPARTS ( year, month, day )**
DATEFROMPARTS returns a date value with the date portion set to the specified year, month and day, and the time portion set to the default. If the arguments are not valid, then an error is raised. If required arguments are null, then null is returned.